# how to hide gear icon Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, css, html

I would like to hide the gear icon in Sharepoint 2013. I would prefer to do so using script editor. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You want to hide the gear icon from one specific page or from all the pages in SharePoint site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the PowerShell for you-

```
#Define the Web URL & List Name $WebUrl = "Your site URL"
$ListToHide = "AppConfig" 
#Get the Web 
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl 
#Get the List 
$list = $web.Lists[$ListToHide] 
#Set the Hidden Property 
$list.Hidden = $true $list.Update() 
#Displose Web Object 
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: How do I add this to my site?

Comment: Zach you cannot add this to your site. You will need to open a SharePoint management shell and run the cmdlets to execute this

Answer (score 0):

Zack, I think you need to take a look at [this](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-hide-site-settings-gear-icon/) article.

The best thing about doing this is that it gives you the option to either hide or show the settings gear icon based on the permission of the user that is accessing the page.

It is a great article with all the steps in detail.

Hopefully you find it useful.

Comment: I have looked at that article. However, I just want to hide it on one page, and I don't need anyone to have access to it. if I could hide just site contents that would work as well.

Comment: Oh okay so you want to hide List/Libraries, then better to keep the Gear button intact and write a simple powershell to hide those lists and libraries. If you want the PowerShell let me know and I will change my answer above.

Comment: Yes that would be great! I could also use a how-to-use the powershell if you don't mind.